# uninitialized constant ProfilesController

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an error "uninitialized constant ProfilesController" on my Profiles controller. This is the profiles_controller.rb:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(params[:profile])

    if @profile.save
      redirect_to profile_path, notice: I18n.t('.profile.created')
    else
      render action: "new"
    end
  end
end
```

This is the routes.rb:

```
  resources :profiles, only: [:new, :create]
```

And this the output of rake routes:

```
   profiles POST   /profiles(.:format)                     profiles#create
   new_profile GET    /profiles/new(.:format)                 profiles#new
```

When I click a link for "new_profile_path" I get the error, but to me everything seems OK? The controller name is plural,the routes are OK?

Comment: Did you create the controller manually or use scaffolding? I've hit similar behavior when creating controllers manually before.

Comment: Manually, bt when it didn't work also with a generator. Both have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really strange, I created a Books controller with a generator, renamed everything to Profiles and then it works as normal. As far as I can see the routes are identical. Strange....

Answer (score 2):

You most likely spelled your controller file wrong.  Confirm that file is truly: `/app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when i checked the name of the controller was 'profile_controller.rb'(i had created it manually though). but inside the definition it was "ProfilesController".

class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

```
def index
end

def new     
    @profile =  Profile.new
end

def create  
end
```

end

So if your controller name is correct and you have added the route("resources :profiles") then it will work as expected